# Wordpress: When logged-in characters well displayed, log out, wont recognize them

Tags: wordpress, chars

When I am logged-in, the Spanish special characters like ñ or accentuated vowels display well. When I log out, the web pages show those special chars as weird chars.So it is being in a session that makes the change. This will mean that all visitors (as they are not logged in) will see bad chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use a caching plugin? A lot of caching plugins only show cache when you are not logged in so that can be the reason that the characters are different.

Comment: yes, that was the issue. My client had installed it and that messed everything up. I would never understand why installing so many crappy plugins. The lesser the better.